# ajax comment system on different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been playing around with the webcodo comment system: http://www.webcodo.net/comments-system-using-php-ajax/

DB table: "comments"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `id_post` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I have changed the id_post (this should contain the page id) from int(11) to varchar(32) because the page id I am using is not only made out of numbers.

file: index.php

```
<?php 
// Connect to the database
include('config.php'); 
$id_post = "1"; //the post or the page id
?>
<div class="cmt-container" >
    <?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_post = '$id_post'") or die(mysql_error());;
    while($affcom = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
        $name = $affcom['name'];
        $email = $affcom['email'];
        $comment = $affcom['comment'];
        $date = $affcom['date'];


    ?>
    <div class="cmt-cnt">
        <div class="thecom">
            <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5><span data-utime="1371248446" class="com-dt"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
            <br/>
            <p>
                <?php echo $comment; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->
    <?php } ?>


    <div class="new-com-bt">
        <span>Write a comment ...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="new-com-cnt">
        <input type="text" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
        <input type="text" id="mail-com" name="mail-com" value="" placeholder="Your e-mail adress" />
        <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
        <div class="bt-add-com">Post comment</div>
        <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- end of comments container "cmt-container" -->


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){ 
        //alert(event.timeStamp);
        $('.new-com-bt').click(function(event){    
            $(this).hide();
            $('.new-com-cnt').show();
            $('#name-com').focus();
        });

        /* when start writing the comment activate the "add" button */
        $('.the-new-com').bind('input propertychange', function() {
           $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:0.6});
           var checklength = $(this).val().length;
           if(checklength){ $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:1}); }
        });

        /* on clic  on the cancel button */
        $('.bt-cancel-com').click(function(){
            $('.the-new-com').val('');
            $('.new-com-cnt').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $('.new-com-bt').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        // on post comment click 
        $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
            var theCom = $('.the-new-com');
            var theName = $('#name-com');
            var theMail = $('#mail-com');

            if( !theCom.val()){ 
                alert('You need to write a comment!'); 
            }else{ 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/add-comment.php",
                    data: 'act=add-com&id_post='+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+'&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val(),
                    success: function(html){
                        theCom.val('');
                        theMail.val('');
                        theName.val('');
                        $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
                            $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                            $('.new-com-bt').before(html);  
                        })
                    }  
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

When I use non-numeric characters inside the $id_post variable(in the index.php file). the comment is not generated after I click Post comment, however this is not the case when $id_post contains only numbers.

file: ajax/add-comment.php

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
if($_POST['act'] == 'add-com'):
    $name = htmlentities($name);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $comment = htmlentities($comment);

    // Connect to the database
    include('../config.php'); 


    //insert the comment in the database
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (name, email, comment, id_post)VALUES( '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$id_post')");
    if(!mysql_errno()){
?>

    <div class="cmt-cnt">
        <div class="thecom">
            <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5><span  class="com-dt"><?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i'); ?></span>
            <br/>
            <p><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->

    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So adding comments with only numeric characters inside the variable works fine. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Does id_post and id store the same values?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are you surrre you changed it to varchar(32)..?

Comment: id_post is meant for the page id and id is used for the poster id. Does it cause problems when they have the same values? id contains numbers (1,2,3,4 etc) and id_post contains (1,1,1,1).

Im's sure it is changed to varchar because I can insert text value manually.

Comment: the name of the table is comment or comments???

Comment: the table name is comments

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the javascript:

```
data: 'act=add-com&id_post='+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+'&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val(),
```

should have been outputted:

```
data: 'act=add-com&id_post=+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val(),
```

without the ' '